Why Power BI embedded dashboard won't load
Currently developing an Angular web application that loads a Power BI dashboard (app owns data scenario). Despite the console returning the object embedToken, the dashboard fails to load and remains on the flashing Power BI logo.
There are no error messages in the console, so I suspect that this is linked to a capacity issue? Are there any other reasons this could be happening? For further context, the Power BI Workspace is not yet connected to an embedded capacity.

You need to provide more details on the way you're embedding as from the question it's not clear to know the issue.
You can check if your Embed Config is correct by Embedding your report in the playground. If you're able to embed the report with the config then there might be problem with your code else with the config.
Anyways the question is not clear. Edit the question with more details.
